# Do loop program

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I'm working on this program for my intro to java class. I've been having a lot of issues. I'm using eclipse. The program is supposed to find the average, range, min, and max numbers. I have everything (at least I do according to her notes, which confuse me...) and have put it all into eclipse. It keeps telling me an error that I need a while(); to end the loop. I've already done this...have I put in the wrong place? What am I doing wrong??

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A_Alnor_SquenceOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double input = 0;
        double average;
        double min = in.nextDouble();
        double max = in.nextDouble();

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a value, type -1 to finish: ");
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                input = in.nextDouble();
                if (input == -1) {
                    done = true;
                } else

                    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                        input = in.nextDouble();
                        sum = sum + input;
                        count++;
                    }

                if (count > 0) {
                    average = sum / count;
                }
                while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                    input = in.nextDouble();
                    if (input > max) {
                        max = input;
                    }
                    while (in.hasNextDouble())
                        if (input < min) {
                            min = input;
                        }
                }
            }
            while (done) ;
            {
                System.out.println("The average is " + average + ".");
                System.out.println("The smallest number is " + min + ".");
                System.out.println("The largest number is " + max + ".");
                System.out.println("the range is " + min + " to " + max + ".");
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the location of your added 'while'. Your do-statement should have one as well. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html.

Comment: +1 for one of the better homework questions I have seen on SO

Comment: Yes, you've put it in the wrong place :-). You should move the while (done) line one block out. And there's no need to have the output lines (System.out...) in a block. But as Héctor mentioned, the do-while loop will just re-start the whole process and let you repeat the task forever.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a do..while construct and the do-statement doesn't have any matching while clause at the end of it, maybe due to a misplaced bracket.

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of loops in Java. You seem to be using two kinds:

`while` loop:

```
while (condition) {
    loop-body
}
```

`do` loop:

```
do {
    loop-body
} while (condition);
```

Your outer loop is a `do` loop but is missing the terminating `while (condition)` part. The `loop-body` part of the outer `do` loop itself contains inner loops that are `while` loops. Go over your code structure and you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed using a do while loop without the proper syntax. Remove the outer-most do-statement.

Furthermore: you need to revise a LOT of your code, as this will not terminate. It checks once if the input is -1 (NOTE THIS IS AN INT AND NOT A DOUBLE!!!) and if this is not the case you keep asking doubles from the user (in a whole lot of while statements). Start by creating pseudocode and ensuring that that is correct, because this will not work.

Good luck!